# TextBox not posting values in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have no idea why the TextBox is posting empty in this GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ContatosGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NomeContatoOriginal" HeaderText="Contato Original" readonly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contato Novo">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNomeContatoNovo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NomeContatoNovo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

After fill the first row with some value at TextBox and hit saving button:

```
protected void salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var nomeContatoOriginal = ContatosGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text; // ok, original value
        var nomeContatoNovo = ContatosGrid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text; // always empty
    }
```

The grid's DataBing is called only when !PostBack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly try

```
TextBox txtSNo = (TextBox)ContatosGrid.Rows[0].FindControl("txtNomeContatoNovo");

string nomeContatoNovo = txtSNo.Text;
```